# Why is my Javascript not valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with ID 'adpictureholder', to which I dynamically add (or remove) images.
 On Form submit I want to get SRC values of all these images within that DIV and put them to the value of one hidden input with ID 'piclinkslisttosubmit'. 
 The thing is that my current Javascript does not function as if there is some syntax typo there, but I don't see where. 
Can anyone please have a quick look at it?

```
function copyonsubmit(){
    var strump1 = '';
    var i=0;
    var endi = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes[].length - 1;
    var images = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes[];
    for (i=0;i<=endi;i++)
    {
        strump1 = strump1 + '|' + images[i].src;
    } 
    document.getElementById('piclinkslisttosubmit').value = strump1;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `childNodes[]` to simply `childNodes`.

You don't need to specify that a variable you're referencing is an array by adding brackets.

Answer (score 1):

First off you don't need the `[]` after childNodes. that causes an error.

You also were forgetting that childNodes includes text nodes and would not work properly, because they did not all contain the src property. I've corrected that in the following example:

```
function copyonsubmit() {
    var str = '';
    var textbox = document.getElementById('piclinkslisttosubmit');
    var i = 0;
    var images = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes;
    var numImages = images.length - 1;
    var src = "";
    for (i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
        if (images[i].tagName === "IMG") {
            str += images[i].src + '|';
        }
    }
    str = str.slice(0, -1); // cut off the final |
    textbox.value = str;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NWArL/2/

Secondly you could write this really simply with jQuery.

```
var str = "";
$("#apictureholder").children("img").each(function() {
    str += $(this).attr("src") + "|"; 
})
$("#piclinkslisttosubmit").val(str);
```

Third off make sure to check your console for errors. It was very clear when I ran this code on JSFiddle that it had a problem.

Finally, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `[]` when reading a property value:

```
var images = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes;
```

You can then get the length from the array, instead of reading the property again:

```
var endi = images.length - 1;
```

Comment: Just a typo on length => `var endi = images.length - 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript isn't valid because you keep putting `childNodes[]` you can solve that by replacing `childNodes[]` with simply `childNodes`

```
function copyonsubmit(){
    var strump1 = '';
    var i=0;
    var endi = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes.length - 1;
    var images = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes;
    for (i=0;i<=endi;i++)
    {
        strump1 = strump1 + '|' + images[i].src;
    } 
    document.getElementById('piclinkslisttosubmit').value = strump1;
} ​
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `childNodes[]` to `childNodes` and rest looks fine to me,

[Read about childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.childNodes)

Try,

```
function copyonsubmit(){
    var strump1 = '';
    var i=0;
    var endi = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes.length - 1;
    var images = document.getElementById('adpictureholder').childNodes;
    for (i=0;i<=endi;i++)
    {
        strump1 = strump1 + '|' + images[i].src;
    } 
    document.getElementById('piclinkslisttosubmit').value = strump1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you were using jQuery, but you presented us with vanilla Javascript. I took the liberty of converting your code to jQuery and cleaning it up a bit. The others have already identified your problem, though.

```
function copyonsubmit() {
    var strump1 = '';
    var images = $("#adpictureholder")[0].childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        strump1 += '|' + images[i].src;
    }
    $('#piclinkslisttosubmit').val(strump1);
}​
```